# Many2one value display custom field value in Odoo 9

Tags: odoo-9

I tried to create a simple Many2one field but I need the field value from custom column I have added .

My code :

```
class Partner(osv.Model):

_inherit = 'res.partner'
_rec_name = 'code'

# Add a new column to the res.partner model, by default partners are not
_columns = {
    'code': fields.char('code', index=True),
  }

def name_get(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    if isinstance(ids, (int, long)):
        ids = [ids]
    res = []
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        name = record.code
        if record.parent_id and not record.is_company:
            name = "%s, %s" % (record.parent_name, name)
        if context.get('show_address_only'):
            name = self._display_address(cr, uid, record, without_company=True, context=context)
        if context.get('show_address'):
            name = name + "\n" + self._display_address(cr, uid, record, without_company=True, context=context)
        if context.get('show_email') and record.email:
            name = "%s <%s>" % (name, record.email)
        res.append((record.id, name))
    return res


class cst_order(osv.Model):
_name = 'cst.order'
_description = 'CST Orders'
_rec_name = 'code'

_columns = {
    'name_ref': fields.many2one('res.partner', ' Code Name',  required=True,),
    'address_change': fields.boolean('Change Address', ),
}
```

In my "name_ref" field I need a value of "code" instead of "name"
Used `_rec_name` and `name_get` but it always display only Customer name not my code ref.
Please anyone help me to sort this.

Comment: Keep in mind that it will also effects in Sales, Purchases, Inventory everywhere *res.partner* field has *Many2one* relational type.

Comment: Yes , this is affecting all partner field. I need a solution only in my custom field

Comment: Is there is any other way to proceed which type is better to implement ?

Comment: I did this by customized of read() ,name_get(),name_search() methods.

Answer (score 0):

did you make sure that your code work well may be is not calling your code at all because of some thing you missed if you overrid the name_get  than it should display what you want.did you put the python model in the **ini**.py see if the framework is calling the new method use debug tools

Comment: changing in name_get will get result but it affects all field , expecting only a solution in my custom field.

Comment: many2one field call this method to render the search result and it's a standard method it's called from all the many2one field you may want to think related field and try to find a solution for it